# How to start working with Augmented Reality?

Tags: augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality

Is there any way to start with Augmented Reality? Is there any innovation team from which i can learn and contribute? Is it restricted to apps only in I.T. or can we also implement any otherthing with the help of Augmented Reality within IT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below links will give you some idea on the list of available sdk's for developing applications using Augmented Reality .

> http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks
>     https://creator.zoho.com/reitmayr/augmented-reality-sdks/view-embed/AR_SDKs

Wikitude and Vuforia sdk's are the most common one's for Augmented Reality applications.
Try the below link to get started with Augmented Reality!!

https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-an-ar-android-app-with-vuforia-and-unity/

Comment: Thank You. I'll go through to these links.

Answer (score 0):

your question is very broad. I think you can try and start by using ARToolKit. http://artoolkit.org/
ARToolKit has a great community from which you can learn and also it is open source so you can have a look at the source and contribute back as well.

I don't get your last question about I.T. but you can do a lot with AR

Comment: Okay. I'll start working with that community. Thank You.  :)